# How to detect Print command has finished in TWebBrowser?

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  vaIn, vaOut: OleVariant;
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('http://www.google.com');
  while WebBrowser1.ReadyState < READYSTATE_COMPLETE do
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  WebBrowser1.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER, vaIn, vaOut);

  // HOWTO: WAIT until print <strike>job</strike> dialog is done or canceled

  // UPDATE (1):
  WebBrowser1.Enabled := False;
  WebBrowser1.OnCommandStateChange := WebBrowser1CommandStateChange;
end;

procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1CommandStateChange(Sender: TObject; Command: Integer; Enable: WordBool);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('%d : %d : %d', [WebBrowser1.QueryStatusWB(OLECMDID_PRINT), Command, Ord(Enable)]));
  // TODO: after LAST event when the print dialog closes:
  // WebBrowser1.OnCommandStateChange := nil;
end;
```

Same goes for Preview:
`WebBrowser1.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINTPREVIEW, OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT, vaIn, vaOut);`

I need to wait (or trigger an event) until the `Print` / `Print Preview` dialogs are done, and user has selected either print or cancel.

**UPDATE (1)**

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491560/twebbrowser-modal-print-dialog) I tested the `OnCommandStateChange`.
It is fired **after** print or cancel in the Print dialog. but it can be fired 1 or 2 times **before** the dialog opens.

**UPDATE (2)**
Found a workaround that might do the trick (it's a basic idea):

```
procedure TForm1.WaitPrintDialog;
var
  t1, t2: DWORD;
  w, wpd: HWND;
begin
  t1 := GetTickCount();
  t2 := t1;
  wpd := 0;
  while ((wpd = 0) and (t2 - t1 <= 5000)) do // 5 sec timeout
  begin
    w := FindWindowEx(0, 0, 'Internet Explorer_TridentDlgFrame', nil);
    if (w <> 0) and (GetWindow(w, GW_OWNER) = Self.Handle) then
    begin
      wpd := w;
    end;
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    t2 := GetTickCount();
  end;
  if wpd <> 0 then // found and no timeout
    while IsWindow(wpd) and (not Application.Terminated) do
    begin
      Application.HandleMessage; // Application.ProcessMessages;
    end;
end;
```

usage:

```
WebBrowser1.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER, vaIn, vaOut);
WaitPrintDialog;
ShowMessage('Print Done!');
```

works both for `OLECMDID_PRINT` and `OLECMDID_PRINTPREVIEW`
please tell me what you think...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I've been looking for a solution I've found the [`PRINT_WAITFORCOMPLETION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa769937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) flag few days ago but can't get it to work. And the trick was quite easy (see [note](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=338787) nr. 4). I've been wrong with passing the third parameter of [`ExecWB`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752117%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method for the [`OLECMDID_PRINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691264%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) command as variant type [`VT_I4`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc237865%28v=prot.13%29.aspx) but it is overloaded and for [`PRINT_WAITFORCOMPLETION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa769937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) must be converted to the exact type [`VT_I2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc237865%28v=prot.13%29.aspx), what is in Delphi represented as a [`smallint`](http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/aa121404b.htm).

Here is how to make the print dialog modal (also answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491560/twebbrowser-modal-print-dialog) by accident :)

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  vaIn: OleVariant;
  vaOut: OleVariant;
const
  PRINT_WAITFORCOMPLETION = $02;
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('http://www.google.com');
  while WebBrowser1.ReadyState < READYSTATE_COMPLETE do
    Application.ProcessMessages;

  vaIn := OleVariant(VarAsType(PRINT_WAITFORCOMPLETION, varSmallint));
  WebBrowser1.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER, vaIn, vaOut);

  ShowMessage('Print dialog has been closed ...');
end;
```

Unfortunately you can't get any feedback if user sent the document to the printer queue or cancelled the dialog. The [`IDM_PRINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa769937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has no output value, which would return this. Another thing is that even if user accepts the printing dialog it doesn't mean that the document will be physically printed. For this you would have to, as Remy said, monitor the printer queue.

Comment: The [`PRINT_WAITFORCOMPLETION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa769937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) flag you can use even with the `OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER` command option, where the processing of the line would mean that document has been sent to the printer queue.

Comment: seems to do exactlly what I want with `OLECMDID_PRINT` but does not work with `OLECMDID_PRINTPREVIEW`

Comment: Yeah, there are no optional flags for [IDM_PRINTPREVIEW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa769938%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). But I've found [this post](http://www.ms-news.info/f3731/waiting-for-custom-ie-print-templates-to-complete-how-1749488.html) which (if I get it right) uses something undocumented, an array of 5 elements even for [IDM_PRINTPREVIEW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa769938%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), but hard to say if it works. I'm not familiar with safe arrays, so try to ask another question _How to detect PrintPreview command has finished in TWebBrowser?_ ;)

Comment: I've tried to rewrite the post linked in my previous comment to Delphi but it seems it doesn't work (or I've made a mistake somewhere). Btw. the preview dialog itself is modal in the meaning of topmost. Further investigations I would let for the others in a separate question if needed :)

Comment: Don't quit when you are so close to solution ;)
btw, I don't think that the code you posted in the previous comment will do the trick. they still use `$02` as the 5 element of the array. ie: `dwFlags = 2;`

Comment: True, that's the most mysterious on that, if I get it right, then they are passing the `$02` flag constant through that array even to the [`IDM_PRINTPREVIEW.`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa769938%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) command which should have only one optional parameter `path to a custom template`, so why that array at all (and it seems to be based on some correspondence with MS). This command should expect only the template file name.

Answer (score 2):

The print job is spooled and outputted to the printer driver by the OS in the background. The WebBrowser does not tell you when it is finished. ExecWB() exits once the print job has been queued. You would have to monitor the printer queue directly to know what it is doing.

Comment: I want to detect when the print dialog is done, not when the actual printing job is finished.

Answer (score 0):

The following code makes the Print dialogbox a model dialog box, so that only when the use done with the Print dialog he will come back to the application.

```
WebBrowser1.ExecWB OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT, 2, 0
```